# Throw entity field value from submission to route path?

Tags: 8, entities, routes

I have created two entities and I want to connect them by route.
my edit route is:

```
entity.entity_two.edit_form:

  path: 
'/property/configuration/communication/{entity_one}/variant/{entity_two}/edit'

  defaults:

    _entity_form: communication_variant.edit
    _title: 'Add/Edit Email Variant'
    entity_one: '%id'
  options:

    parameters:
      entity_one:
        type: 'entity_one'
      communication_variant:
        type: entity:node
```

but I get an error on edit path as it says: entity one is empty but as i check entity one has value in the table.
so my idea is that on submission of entity two form, I get entity_one id by entity reference and set in my route. so I want to implement that idea any help?

Comment: that type definition there looks wrong, are you sure that is what you used? What are your actual entity type ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to pass the value in edit route without using route subscriber or any pram converter. I will pass the value to Entity list builder default operations function. From there I can change the URL of edit and delete.

```
public function getDefaultOperations(EntityInterface $entity) {
    /* @var $entity \Drupal\my_module\Entity\entity_two */
    $operations = parent::getDefaultOperations($entity);
    $cid = $entity->cid->getString();
    $edit= \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.entity_two.edit_form',array('entity_one' => $cid , 'entity_two' => $entity->id()));
    $operations['edit'] = array(
        'title' => $this->t('edit'),
        'weight' => 10,
        'url' => $edit,
    );
    $delete= \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.entity_two.delete_form',array('entity_one' => $cid , 'entity_two' => $entity->id()));
    $operations['delete'] = array(
        'title' => $this->t('delete'),
        'weight' => 11,
        'url' => $delete,
    );

    return $operations;

}
```